# Using PHP CURL to post data to external URL and redirect

Tags: php, curl

Here's my scenario.
I have an external URL : https://staging.mead.com.ph/login/sso
Now I have to post data to that URL, assuming like the one below :

1. Name
2. Type
3. Mobile Num

Now, after posting I have to be redirected to the
[redirect_url] inside curl_getinfo(). [redirect_url] has the following value : **https://staging.mead.com.ph/login/key=abcde**

HOWEVER,after echoing the result of the curl_exec, it says "***Object Moved Here***" and "**HERE**" redirects to **https://myservername/login/key=abcde**
instead of the **https://staging.mead.com.ph/login/key=abcde**

Here's my code :

```
$url    =  "https://staging.mead.com.ph/login/key=abcde";
$token  = "token1234";
$params = array(
    "Name" => "Ana",
    "Type" => "A",
    "Mobilenum" => "0919123456"
    );
 foreach($params as $key => $value) { 
    $fields .= $key . '=' . $value . '&'; 
 }
 rtrim($fields, '&');
 $post = curl_init();

 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);  

 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, PROXY_AUTH);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXY, PROXY_URL);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, PROXY_PORT);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,6);

 $result = curl_exec($post);

 echo $result;

 curl_close($post);
```

What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is redirection code?

Comment: Sorry for this novice question. But do I have to redirect using header?  Doesn't curl works like Form Post wherein it is automatically redirected after posting? :) Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can do it also.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Is there a reason for these:

```
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, PROXY_AUTH);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXY, PROXY_URL);
 curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, PROXY_PORT);
```

If so, you need to use the correct parameters, otherwise delete them.

**------- End of Update ---------**

There are many things that could be going wrong.  There is a way to troubleshoot.

add these options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Then get the Headers, response, and stats

```
$requestHeaderText = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT); 
$skip = intval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE)); 
$responseHeaderText = substr($data,0,$skip);
$response = substr($data,$skip);
$stats = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

In the redirect header you will see a "location", this is where you are being redirected.

You may want to try `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
this will change the request`Content-Type`to`multipart/form-data`

Often cookies are set on the redirect page.  Look for SET-COOKIE in the response Headers.  If there are cookies then you need to use `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`

Also look for javascript in the response.  Sometimes the redirect is done using javascript while performing security checks etc.

You may want to change `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to false.  Then you will only get the headers and stats for the first request.

Comment: Hi, thanks! On my header, I noticed that the location is indicated as /login/key=abcde... Maybe that's the reason why I am being redirected to https://myservername/login/key=abcde instead of https://staging.mead.com.ph/login/key=abcde... How do I make it redirect to the correct external URL? :(

Comment: You must have a typo in your url.  mead.com.ph is for sale.